How to configure NIFI ConsumePOP3 processor for outlook 365 to get email?
I could make the ConsumePOP3 processor work with my Gmail account.
However, it does not work with Outlook 365.
I am following exactly the same steps.

The password is the app password generated from that outlook 365 account.

What is wrong?

I have confirmed with microsoft outlook support team that Microsoft no longer supports POP3 or IMAP with app passprod connection. As such we could confirm that NIFI consumePOP3 will not work with outlook 365.

Is your email account type Gmail?
Before configuring your POP account, make sure to turn on this POP download option. More information，see：
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en

As far as I know, different account types require different port information. It is recommended that you contact your email provider.

OP has it working in google, they're trying another provider
